# Mac OS X sysctl get total and free memory size

Tags: macos, command-line, memory

How to get on MAC OS X using sysctl used and free memory ? Searched for `sysctl -a | grep vm` or `sysctl -a | grep mem` but didn't found anything relevant.

Comment: Also see [Is there a Mac OS X Terminal version of the “free” command in Linux systems?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4286) on the Apple Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't.

Well, except for total memory size, which you could have found with `sysctl -a | grep mem` (`hw.memsize = 4294967296` on my machine).

`vm_stat` displays the same information as `Activity Monitor.app` does, you just need to multiply the value you want by page size. Both are provided in the output.

Comment: vm_stat: pages free: 12054 .. 12054 * 4096 / 1024 / 1024 = 47.08 and Activity monitor shows: 103 MB http://grab.by/6KSD VM_stats output: http://pastebin.com/BJcxPswv Why i get wrong values ?

Comment: Add `Pages speculative` to the free ones. You might have noticed that free+active+inactive+wired down don't add to the total size displayed in Activity Monitor.

Comment: the `grep` doesn't seem required - on my MacBook Pro, `sysctl hw.memsize` also works and prints `hw.memsize: 8589934592`

Answer (score 5):

No grep is needed.

```
sysctl -n hw.memsize
```

Answer (score 4):

```
top -l 1 | grep PhysMem: | awk '{print $10}'
```

`top -l 1` runs `top` in *logging mode* (e.g. file output, not display/terminal output) for one iteration, then quits. The `grep`/`awk` filters for the free memory value in `top` output.

Comment: YMMV. On Sierra, `top -l 1 | grep PhysMem:` gives me `PhysMem: 9674M used (1752M wired), 6701M unused.` so I used `top -l 1 | grep PhysMem: | awk '{print $6}'`. Thanks!

Comment: my result is `PhysMem: 15G used (1815M wired, 2047M compressor), 265M unused.` so `$10` prints nothing. But this is the only answer that kind of gives the correct free memory size

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `top` command to view your memory usage in realtime?

**UPDATE:**

You can use the following commands:

```
sysctl -a | grep hw.usermem
sysctl -a | grep hw.physmem
```

For a complete listing type **man sysctl** in terminal.

Comment: Probably for use in a script.

Comment: Both `usermem` and `physmem` display useless values for systems over 2GB RAM. Both are probably bounded by a signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: Maybe i can use top to get single output. After i get the output i will parse needed values.

Comment: Useless use of `grep`... `sysctl hw.memsize`=total, `sysctl hw.physmem`, `sysctl hw.usermem`

Comment: @DanielBeck is right, `hw.memsize` is what you probably want for total.  [See my comment here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583736/determine-physical-mem-size-programmatically-on-osx#comment30400880_818741)

Answer (score 0):

mac os x/ linux

```
$ sysctl -a | grep '^hw\.m'
hw.memsize: 8589934592
```

Comment: This looks like a minor tweak to existing answers.  Probably more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: the same as `sysctl hw.memsize`